# What's the term for telling the DMV that your vehicle isn't in use?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, terminology

In Sweden, when we don't use a vehicle, we tell our local DMV that it's not going to be on the road. Then, they sign it as such and we can pay less or no insurance (although we're extremely limited in terms of the permitted usage).

I want to tell that to someone about a vehicle and initially I said that it might be *unregistered* but that's not correct terminology. The vehicle is registered, it has plates and an owner.

What's the correct term for it in English? As it's a legal term, I wouldn't be surprised if it's different on the different sides of the oceans.

Comment: I have found it very common to say the vehicle is "Off the Road" in Canada. Going to the Canadian verision of the DMV and telling them this would be understood. I have heard the term in the US too

Answer (score 11):

I just found out that the correct term in UK is

> *SORN*

which stands for *Statutory Off Road Notification*.

I also just learned that *DMV* (*Department of Motorization and Vehicles*) isn't called *RA* (*Road Administration*) but *DVLA* (*Driver and Vehicle Licensing Agency*).

Comment: Yes, those terms are correct in the UK. +1

Answer (score 6):

In California, this is called [Planned Non-Operation (PNO)](https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/dmv/detail/pubs/brochures/fast_facts/ffvr01):

> PNO means that the vehicle will not be driven, towed, stored, or parked on public roads or highways for the **entire** registration year.

From [another site](http://www.carsdirect.com/dmv/car-registration-for-non-operation-status-vehicles), I found:

> The DVM offers a special non-operational car registration for non operation vehicles which are neither to be driven nor parked on the communal street.

Comment: HAHAHAHA, oh, that's rich. The vehicle we're talking about is registered in Finland and the [name of company is literally PNO](http://pno.fi/)...

Comment: +1 Though the one thing that does concern me is what if you are only planning to not operate your vehicle for part of the registration period and not in its entirety as dictated by California's PNO definition?

Comment: @KonradViltersten That's really funny :D You should wait longer before accepting an answer in general. Here, others can provide you with other terminology from other  regions, and even more accurate ones.

Comment: @DogLover You probably pay some kind of early fee or you're simply out of luck. Thankfully, this is not the site for that :D

Comment: @Max Indeed. Though I was actually referring to the definition itself. If you're operating a vehicle for part of a registration period, the definition suggests that it can't be PNO even if it is left alone for the rest of the year.

Comment: @DogLover I don't know what the appropriate term would be. I don't think it mentioned it on that site. But that's why I included the second definition, so that at least the DMV people will have an idea of what OP wants to do or file.

Comment: @Max As suggested.